# Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.CouldNotRetrieveSearchTokenException ,Could not retrieve a search token?

Tags: api, proxy, sitecore, sitecore8, coveo

I am configuring `coveo` in `sitecore`. I am following the steps configuring for on-premises as given below link.

https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV3/Setting+Up+Coveo+for+Sitecore

https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SearchREST/Windows+Service+Configuration+File

But I am getting below exception

```
Exception: Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.CouldNotRetrieveSearchTokenException
Message: Could not retrieve a search token
Source: Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy
   at Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.SearchTokenStore.RetrieveNewSearchToken(UserID[] p_UserIds)
   at Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.SearchTokenStore.GetSearchToken(UserID[] p_UserIds)
   at Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.ProxyHttpHandler.AddSearchTokenToRequest(HttpContext p_Context, HttpWebRequest p_Request)
   at Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.ProxyHttpHandler.SetDefaultResponse(HttpContext p_Context)
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.Rest.SitecoreRestHttpHandler.OnReverseProxyRequest(HttpContext p_Context)
   at Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.ProxyHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext p_Context)
```

Nested Exception

```
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Coveo.Search.Api.Proxy.SearchTokenStore.RetrieveNewSearchToken(UserID[] p_UserIds)
```

Comment: Well first, the `CouldNotRetrieveSearchTokenException` error was added in Coveo for Sitecore 4, so you should follow the V4 steps instead of the V3 steps.

Comment: you can also try posting at https://answers.coveo.com/